# Visual Studio doesn't show my web service function summary as calling that function

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-services, summary, function-call

I want to show my summaries when the function is getting called but I can not see however I wrote summaries. Here is my codes:

calling the webmethod:

[image]

webservice side: 
[image]

Comment: Do you want to see xml comments in the web service application or in the application which created proxy to consume web service?

Comment: I want to see the xml comments of the function is called from anywhere

Comment: When you looked at to proxy class of web services, you will see there is no any comments of your classes which are defined in web service. Web service doesn't push the comments of methods Mr. Çağın :)

Comment: Thanks a  lot Mr.Cem the master of team:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As uzay95 said, web service doesn't push the comments of methods.